# Tic tac toe, user 1 for a position to put an X (then output array), then user 2 for a position to put O

Tags: java, arrays, input

I have the 3x3 grid that I need to store the user's input into. I've started making a scanner to make allow the user to input. My only problem is trying to input a String data type where a char exists.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bwbw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int WIDTH = 3, HEIGHT = 3;
        char[][] board = new char[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
                board[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write  your problem little clearly? What are you trying to do and what is not happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make one more array containing 1-9 values, and print it on the screen in 3x3 grid which acts as the position of the X,O to enter.
thus the key value should activate that element in the Tic tac toe grid with either X or O depends on your conditional logic.